# Redis and ACL deprecation warning : Allowing a first arg of an otherwise blocked command is a misuse of ACL

Tags: redis

I can currently see a deprecation warning in my logs: Allowing a first arg of an otherwise blocked command is a misuse of ACL and may get disabled in the future (offender: +info|replication)

The corresponding user is defined as follow :
user haproxy-user on #13412...43534 resetchannels -@all +info|replication +ping

This user should be only allowed to ping the server and check 'info replication' section to know if the server is role:master or role:slave

This works fine right now (redis 7.0.10 on Debian) but I can't figure out how to modify this user's acl to get rid of the warning.

I didn't modify my current config as I don't know what exactly I should do. Your help is welcome.